# Processing JSON data in Rails controller (mapping JSON request body to params hash)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am trying to process JSON data posted to a Rails (3.1.0) controller by accessing the data through the params hash. Unfortunately, Rails does not seem to process the data automatically (as the documentation and other questions on StackOverflow suggest).

The controller looks like:

```
class Api::EventsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

  def create
    unless params['event']['timestamp'].nil?
      ...
    end
    ...

    render :json => { :status => :success }
  end
end
```

The HTTP request looks like this (captured using tcpdump):

```
POST /api/locations/1/events HTTP/1.1
Date: Mon, 10 Oct 2011 21:57:22 GMT+00:00
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Accept: application/json
Host: 10.0.2.2:3000
User-Agent: Restlet-Framework/2.1rc1
Authorization: Basic ...
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: Keep-Alive

4e
{"event":{"data_source":"ANDROID","timestamp":1318283841768,"type":"LEAVING"}}
0
```

In the above example, `params['event']` is always `nil`. Using `ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(request.body)` to parse the JSON data works, but I would like to map the request body to parameters automatically.

**Edit:** `request.params` just contains routing information and `request.request_parameters` is completely empty.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that you're sending a correct request? Reffering to [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.6.1), your last chunk should be empty to tell the receiver about the end of the transmission. Just adopt your request like that:

```
...
4e CRLF
{"event":{"data_source":"ANDROID","timestamp":1318283841768,"type":"LEAVING"}} CRLF
0 CRLF
CRLF
```

You might think of switching from Transfer-Encoding to Content-Length as well.

**Transfer-Encoding** is for *streaming* data. You may send several chunks of data without knowing their size in advance. You have to send an empty chunk to declare the transmission as completed.

**Content-Length** just specifies the Length of the data you will send, so that the receiver knows when the transmission reached the end.

---

Just in case you just forgot to paste that last chunk:

**Overridden?**

Did you override accidentally some of params, parameters, request_parameters, request? Why not try

- `request.params` for the same value or
- `request.request_parameters` for the actual content hash {:event => ...} without the additional dispatch stuff

Comment: You're right about the terminating empty chunk. It is actually sent (and terminated by an extra CRLF sequence, so the request seems to be fine), I just initially missed it because it goes over the wire in a separate packet.

It is a little tricky to change the request as that is all done by the Restlet library, so I do not have control over the actual wire format. I'll ceck your remarks regarding the accidentially overridden methods later, but am quite certain that none of these applies (as I see a basic params hash, which contains the locations_id, in the debugger).

Comment: I also tried request.params and request.request_parameters as you suggested, but they just contain routing information or are completely empty, respectively.

Comment: Well, looking into the parameter parsing code in params_parser.rb, the following line rings a bell: `return false if request.content_length.zero?` Looks as if chunked encoding is not supported...

Comment: rack started the support for chunks in [1.0.0](https://github.com/rack/rack) in 2009 and it seems like ActionDispatch doesn't need to care about it because the middleware runs when the whole request is loaded (correct me, if I'm wrong). The code you quoted doesn't seem to be related as simple GET-requests don't have a request body neither (and therefore a content_length zero. I checked this)

Comment: Yep, GET requests do not have a body, but POSTs do. I observed the quoted code being executed in the debugger, so it is definitely relevant. The code is from ruby 1.9.2, though, so maybe JRuby or 1.9.3 close this gap. I'll test and report...